# WebClient SparkWeb vs JwChat for openfire server (XMPP)

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, multiuserchat

I am  newbie in XMPP. I am trying to create a multi user chat using in a spring framework project with xmpp. I am using **openfire** as chat server. I am very confused for what client should i use for chat. I have gone through some like **SparkWeb**, **JwChat** and **strophej**. But can't figure out for which one should i go?